# ng-repeat create table columns with array failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why this won't work?

Controller:

```
$scope.dates = ['1-1-2017', '2-1-2017'];
```

Template:

```
<tr>
  <td ng-repeat="date in dates">
    {{ date }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

but it work with `<div>`:

```
<div ng-repeat="date in dates">
  {{ date }}
</div>
```

Comment: I think that your problem may be such different. Post your all code here.

Comment: your code works. Don't forget the `<table>` element http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/8842/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works when it is embedded inside the tag **`<table>`**

```js
var testApp= angular.module('test',[])
angular.module('test').controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.dates = ['1-1-2017', '2-1-2017'];
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
</head>

<body ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <table>
 <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="date in dates">
      {{date}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are not binding using `<table>` as parent element, So try this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="date in dates">
            {{date}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Update**:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/srzof334/1/
```

See this and try to remove `table` and then check. See for [detail](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459)

It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>TASKS</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="sample1Controller">
<div>
   <table>
   <span> ng-repeat in table:</span>
   <tr ng-repeat="date in dates">
    <td>
      {{date}}
    </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
   <div>
   <span>ng-repeat in div:</span>
   <div ng-repeat="date in dates">
  {{date}}
</div>
</div>

</body>
<script>
var app=angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("sample1Controller",["$scope",function($scope){
$scope.dates = ['1-1-2017', '2-1-2017'];

}]);


</script>
</html>
```